# Unix test for existence or file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
[ -f /tmp/myfile.txt ] && echo "File exists" || echo "No such file"
```

How does this work? Specifically the the evaluation of `&&` and `||`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&&` and `||` are control operators that determine whether the following command should be executed based on the exit status of the prior command. From `man (1) bash`:

> The control operators && and || denote AND lists and OR lists, respectively.  An AND list has the form
>
> ```
>   command1 && command2
> ```
>
> command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero.
>
> An OR list has the form
>
> ```
>   command1 || command2
> ```
>
> command2  is  executed  if  and only if command1 returns a non-zero exit status.
>   The return status of AND and OR lists is the exit status of the last
>   command executed in the list.

`[`, or `test`, returns a *zero* exit status if the command passes the test. From `help test`:

> test: test [expr]
>       Exits with a status of 0 (true) or 1 (false) depending on
>       the evaluation of EXPR.

So when you do

```
[ -f /tmp/myfile.txt ] && echo foo || echo bar
```

what you're really saying is (read this carefully, please) *If the file exists, echo foo. If the file does not exist **or the `echo foo` command fails**, echo bar.*

This is the subtle, but critical difference between these control operators and an `if…then` command.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. In other words:<br/>
<br/>
Given:<br/>
<br/>
[ -f /tmp/myfile.txt ] && echo "File exists" || echo "No such file"<br/>
<br/>
file exists:<br/>
<br/>
myfile exists, returns 0, echo<br/>
<br/>
File does not exist:<br/>
<br/>
myfile does not exist, returns 1, echo not executed because non zero, second echo executes because previous echo returns non-zero<br/>

Comment: Thanks to all the explanations, I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that it runs from left to right

first it evaluates -f /tmp/myfile.txt which is true if the file exists and is a file

next it tries to evaluate the && which takes a left and a right argument.  It's a logical "and"

it does lazy evaluation from left to right so if the file test is true then it checks the echo command for true, which it does by executing it.  Presumably "true" in shell world means it executes normally with a zero exit code

If either of the file test or the echo ( the two args for the && ) are false then the output from the && is false and this is passed to the right

The || is a logical "or" and also has a left and right arg.  If the left arg is true then it stops there as it is lazy

If the left arg is false ( the file doesn't exist ) then the right hand arg is run